# Django: Saving a user profile

Tags: python, django, python-2.x, user-profile

This is very basic, but I can't find anything on it. I have a user profile defined in the following way:

```
def create_user_info(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserInfo.objects.create(user=instance)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Now how do I set the properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off. Monkey-patching `User` is not the correct approach. Set `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'yourapp.UserInfo'` in settings.py, and then you can use `user_instance.get_profile()` automatically to get the profile.

So, then to modify the profile you just do:

```
profile = user.get_profile()
profile.some_field = 'some value'
profile.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason all these websites said it was a better approach (makes the code cleaner), but I changed it back to what the Django documentation says.

Comment: in django1.5 AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE is deprecated: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE